# Remove unwanted chars in log message

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script that goes and gets the LastLogonTimestamp for each computer in my domain. I set this script up to write to my system log file. Everything is working correctly except that I am getting `@{......}` in my log message but not when I print on screen. I am sending these logs to a SIEM and it does not like the additional characters.

Script:

```
$dcs = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -NotLike '*Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem

foreach($dc in $dcs) { 
    # Implement LastLogonTime log item, if necessary
    try {
        # create a new event log type of "FreePhysicalMemory"
        [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource($dc.Name, "System")
    } catch {
        # ignore if the above fails.
    }

    $LastLogon = Get-ADComputer $dc.Name -Properties LastLogonTimestamp |
                 Select-Object @{Name="LastLogon"; Expression={
                     [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)
                 }}

    # for debugging purposes. comment out when happy    
    $LastLogon

    # logging entries for SIEM
    Write-EventLog -LogName System -Source $dc.Name -EventID 8007 -EntryType Information -Message "LastLogonTimeStamp `n $LastLogon" -Category 1
}
```

Results:

[image: Screenshot: eventlog record]

Comment: Easiest to implement `$LastLogon.LastLogon` You are seeing the string representation of your object. It is not a [datetime] value but an object with a [datetime] property. Common PS gotcha. Also consider `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` (don't know if that works for calculated properties of the top of my head but it should.)

Comment: Matt, Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried to add $LastLogon.LastLogon in several places, but it either does not work or gives same results. What should I change to $LastLogon?

Comment: Why not use `LastLogonDate` on the Computer object which is already the string DateTime representation of LastLogonTimeStamp ? `$LastLogon = Get-ADComputer $dc.Name -Properties LastLogonDate | select -expand LastLogonDate` Also be careful with where you are querying as LastLogonTimeStamp and LastLogonDate are only replicated if older than 14 days.

Comment: That did work, but it is not in human readable form.

Comment: BenH that worked great thank you.